# How to combine query from last 1 hour with max time for each id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with time series data. To check if the data quality especially whether the sensors are writing to the database I implemented a SQL view which gives me the average of the last hour and I can see the data with this code:

```
SELECT avg(value) AS avg,
       location
       name
FROM measurement
WHERE datetime >= (now() - '01:00:00'::interval)
GROUP BY location, name
```

The time serie data table looks like this:

```
    datetime                    value   location   name
0    2018-01-01 13:35:00+01:00   0.22    HLN    NO2
1    2018-01-01 13:35:00+01:00   0.31    HLN    CO
2    2018-01-01 13:35:00+01:00   1.15    HLN    NO
3    2018-01-01 13:40:00+01:00   1.80    AIS    NO2
4    2018-01-01 13:40:00+01:00   2.60    AIS    CO
5    2018-01-01 13:40:00+01:00   2.30    AIS    NO
6    2018-01-01 13:45:00+01:00   2.25    HLN    NO2
7    2018-01-02 13:45:00+01:00   2.14    HLN    CO
8    2018-01-02 13:45:00+01:00   2.96    HLN    NO
9    2018-01-02 14:35:00+01:00   0.76    HLN    NO2
10   2018-01-02 14:35:00+01:00   0.80    HLN    CO
11   2018-01-02 14:35:00+01:00   1.19    HLN    NO
12   2018-01-02 14:40:00+01:00   1.10    AIS    NO2
13   2018-01-02 14:40:00+01:00   2.87    AIS    CO
14   2018-01-02 14:40:00+01:00   2.80    AIS    NO
15   2018-01-02 14:45:00+01:00   3.06    HLN    NO2
16   2018-01-02 13:45:00+01:00   2.86    HLN    CO
17   2018-01-02 13:45:00+01:00   2.22    HLN    NO
```

Since I have a huge database and some sensors stopped writing data 2 weeks ago, from time to time I check the `MAX(datetime)` for each location to see which one sent the last time the data.

Now my question is, can I expand my sql query to also include the max time for each location?

I know for example from the initial view that 2 sensors don't send data to the database, since they are not visible in the last hour of the data and I know from the `MAX(datetime)` that they stopped 2 weeks ago to send data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution with LATERAL JOIN**

```
SELECT avg(m.value) AS avg
     , m.location
     , m.name
     , s.max_datetime
  FROM measurement AS m
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(
SELECT max(datetime) AS max_datetime
  FROM measurement AS p
 WHERE p.location = m.location
   AND p.name = m.name
) AS s
 WHERE m.datetime >= ('2018-01-02 14:40:00+01:00' :: timestamp - interval '1 hour')
 GROUP BY m.location, m.name, s.max_datetime
```

**Solution with JOIN**

```
SELECT avg.*, max.max_datetime
  FROM
     ( SELECT avg(value) AS avg
            , location
            , name
         FROM measurement
        WHERE datetime >= '2018-01-02 14:40:00+01:00' :: timestamp - interval '1 hour'
        GROUP BY location, name
     ) AS avg
 INNER JOIN
     ( SELECT location
            , name
            , max(datetime) AS max_datetime
         FROM measurement
        GROUP BY location, name
     ) AS max
   ON avg.location = max.location
  AND avg.name = max.name
```

The EXPLAIN ANALYSE shows that solution with JOIN is faster.

See the results in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=52a9d10367a8165e0b253d9596d2e78b)

Comment: What I am confused with is the time. The MAX(datetime) should scan the whole database and give me the MAX(DATETIME) for each location whereas the first part of the VIEW should only give me the last hour average of the values. Is this the case in your solution?

Comment: Yes absolutely. This is why there are two joined queries in every solution, one query scanning the whole table, the other query with the WHERE condition so that to limit the table scan to the last hour from now.

Comment: I tried you solution and I get a third column with the max_datetime and it shows the max datetime. Problem is, I know for example that two sensors don't send data since 2021-11-20 and this two sensors are not in the result table with the MAX(datetime) of 2021-11-20. It seems the second query can only access data from 1 hour ago. I tried the solution with Join.

Comment: In both solutions, max(datetime) is computed over the whole table, BUT in both solutions, the displayed list of sensors is limited to the one with a record in the last hour. In the second solution, you can simply replace `INNER JOIN` by `RIGHT JOIN` so that to get max(datetime) for all the sensors. In the first solution you can't do that because of the  `WHERE m.datetime >= ('2018-01-02 14:40:00+01:00' :: timestamp - interval '1 hour')` clause which limits the final list.

Comment: Thanks, seems logical and I tried it and now it shows me the missing two sensors, but the results shows 'NULL' instead of the location. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Sure, just add `max.*` in the top level `SELECT` clause